# Apply SublimeLinter to configuration files with no extentions

Tags: sublimelinter

How would I get SublimeLinter to lint a file such as .babelrc (json or js). The "lint this view" option is greyed out.

Here's my user config: https://gist.github.com/86355281aca4d4fba941

Comment: Which specific extension are you using, or are you using SublimeLinter on Sublime Text 2?

Comment: @MattDMo - added link to my user config - namely eslint, json and htmllint. I would like my babelrc file linted with esline I suppose as other rc files don't seem to be strict json. In the jshint plugin days I would just manually call the js linter but now this is no longer an option.

Comment: Try setting the syntax of the file to the default Javascript syntax (View -> Syntax -> Javascript -> Javascript) and see if the linter becomes active. I'm looking at the [source](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jshint/blob/master/linter.py#L21) and it seems to require a certain syntax in order to work. It's worth a shot...

Comment: @MattDMo thanks that worked. Tricky. Since there is no extension I have to add each rc filename to the ST syntax settings. Works but a step way down from the jshint plugin.

Comment: good to hear it worked. Want me to make an answer out of it, or not bother?

Comment: I suppose though I feel that there should be a better way such as include file patterns in the linter settings but all I see is exclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SublimeLinter` linters only work on files that have a defined syntax applied, which is recognized by the linter via the [`"syntax_map"`](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/global_settings.html#syntax-map) setting and the [`syntax`](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/linter_attributes.html#syntax) variable assigned in the linter's `linter.py` file. So, for example, `SublimeLinter-eslint` [defines `syntax`](https://github.com/roadhump/SublimeLinter-eslint/blob/master/linter.py#L23) as `('javascript', 'html', 'javascriptnext', 'javascript (babel)', 'javascript (jsx)', 'jsx-real')`, meaning it will only work on files whose syntax maps to one of those values. Unfortunately, there is no setting in SublimeLinter that allows you to pass a list of file extensions to be linted; everything works by syntax.

The long and short of it is that you'll need to assign a JavaScript syntax to each file you want to lint. This is pretty straightforward: just open a `.babelrc` file, change the syntax to JavaScript, then select **`View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... -> JavaScript -> JavaScript`**. This will create a file `JavaScript.sublime-settings` in your `Packages/User` directory with the following contents:

```js
{
    "extensions":
    [
        "babelrc"
    ]
}
```

You can then edit this file and add any other extensions you wish, and when you open them in Sublime they'll automatically be assigned the JavaScript syntax, and you'll be able to lint them.